# Conditional Formatting for multiple cells and ranges in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Thank you for taking the time to read my post

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a list of people and some of these people may be on PTO on some days. I am trying to make a conditional format so when I put in a date that a person has off, it will change color.

The image below shows example cells on what im trying to accomplish. There are two tabs. one named VSB and one named PTO. Bob smith has PTO on 11/28/2020 and I want to create a condition that will change the background color of the cell in column F that matches a column in the PTO Tab

[VSB Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zgfx.png)

[PTO Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxTrG.png)

So I need to create a formula that will check to see if the Employee name and date matches the cells in the PTO tab.

I can include the excel spreadsheet in the post, just dont know the preferred method of doing so

Any Input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional format to F2 for "Use a formula to determine..."

```
=COUNTIFS(PTOsheet!B2:B4000, B2, PTOsheet!C2:C4000,C2)>0
```